# Python smbus lib with Sensirion SGP30

Tags: python-2.7, sensors, raspberry-pi3, i2c

Im trying to read and write i2c messages to/from Sensirion SGP30 sensor with Raspberry Pi 3 but I have hard time to wrap my head around smbus lib.

SGP30 documentation (https://cdn.sos.sk/productdata/46/c9/ba351164/sgp30.pdf) has table that shows hexdecimals to init and start measuring:

[image: SGP30 commands]

And here is how I try to get it up and running:

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x58

time.sleep(.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x2003, [])
time.sleep(.5)
bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x2008, [])
time.sleep(.5)

while 1:
    print bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0)
```

This prints me array

```
[0, 0, 129, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]
```

But sensor is not reacting to alcohol.

What I would really need is tutorial for dummies about i2c communication and same with smbus (python). It seems that every tutorial Ive seen is those "just put these bytes here and you are good to go".

So how can I get this to work? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work.

```
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x58

bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x20, [0x03])
time.sleep(.5)

while 1:
   bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x20, [0x08])
   time.sleep(.6)
   print bus.read_i2c_block_data(address, 0)
   time.sleep(.8)
```

Went thru the documentation again and as it says

> “Measure_air_quality” command has to be sent in regular intervals of 1s to ensure proper operation of the
>   dynamic baseline compensation algorithm.

It seems that sleep times needs to be slightly bigger since loop is not running too smoothly on raspberry pi.

Still didn't find good explanation why I need to split that byte in two.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're aware of this, but the SGP30 requires a VDD of +1.8V. The Pi i2c probably won't operate correctly if you pull up the i2c gates to that voltage, or alternatively, if you are powering the SGP30 from +3.3V it likely had a short but merry life and has now died. Are you powering the SGP30 correctly, and using i2c level shifters for communication? Otherwise the problems you mention are to be expected.

Comment: I have voltage regulator between so everything is fine on that side. Just posted answer how I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this should work. 
Every time you give the bus the command 0x2008 the sensor reply with 6 bytes of information, the first 2 bytes contain CO2 related information, the third one is a checksum, the fourt and the fifth contain tVOC information and the last one is a checksum as well.

```
import time
import sys
import smbus
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x58
reply_buffer = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
reply = [0,0]
bus.write_i2c_block_data(address, 0x20, [0x03])
time.sleep(.5)
while True:

    bus.write_i2c_block_data(address,0x20,[0x08])
    time.sleep(.6)
    block = bus.read_i2c_block_data(address,0)
    for i in range(0,6):
            reply_buffer[i]=block[i]
    for i in range(0,2):
            reply[i]=reply_buffer[i*3]
            reply[i]<<=8
            reply[i]|=reply_buffer[i*3+1]
    print ("Co2 = ", reply[0])
    print ("\n")
    print("TVOC = ", reply[1])
    print ("\n")
    time.sleep(.2)
```